# Http.Request(new Request({})) sent twice

Tags: http, request, angular, response

I am using a http.Request method to make a http call to server. In the browser console I see two http requests. One gives the response as `POST,GET,HEAD` with XHR shown as status 200 and the other gives the right response but the XHR status is shown as other. http.Request is in a service and the subscribe is in the component class.

The service class is

```
export class Httpprovider {
    http: Http;
    constructor(http: Http){
        this.http = http;
    }
    httpReq(url: string, method: string, data: any, header: Headers){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        console.log(headers);

        if (method === 'GET'){ var methods = RequestMethod.Get} 
        else if (method === 'POST'){ var methods = RequestMethod.Post}
        else if (method === 'PUT'){var methods = RequestMethod.Put}
        else if (method === 'PATCH'){var methods = RequestMethod.Patch} 
        else if (method === 'DELETE'){var methods = RequestMethod.Delete}
        else {methods = RequestMethod.Get};

        return this.http.request(new Request({
                    method: methods,
                    url: url,
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    headers: headers
                })).map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that calls `HttpProvider.httpRequ(...)` there is no way to tell.

Comment: please check network tab. you will find one request with `preflight` `option` like @GünterZöchbauer has added in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are subscribing multiple times to `HttpProvider.httpRequ(...).subscribe()` or it's a CORS preflight call (is of type `OPTIONS` AFAIR), therefore it's probably the former.